# Update to Gradle 7.3, Java 17

Tags: java, spring, gradle, swagger

I wanted update gradle to 7.3 from 5.6 and I cant do it. I have this problem during compile project(I have java 17). I read that gradle >7 version has some problems, maybe u know what is wrong? Thanks for answears

This is log after compile project with gradle 7.3:

````
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':api:TemplateServices-api:generateSwaggerCodeDocs' (type 'GenerateSwaggerCode').
  - In plugin 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' type 'org.hidetake.gradle.swagger.generator.GenerateSwaggerCode' property 'adaptorFactory' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' type 'org.hidetake.gradle.swagger.generator.GenerateSwaggerCode' property 'configFile' is annotated with @InputFile but missing a normalization strategy.

    Reason: If you don't declare the normalization, outputs can't be re-used between machines or locations on the same machine, therefore caching efficiency drops significantly.

    Possible solution: Declare the normalization strategy by annotating the property with either @PathSensitive, @Classpath or @CompileClasspath.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_normalization_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' type 'org.hidetake.gradle.swagger.generator.GenerateSwaggerCode' property 'wipeOutputDir' of type boolean shouldn't be annotated with @Optional.

    Reason: Properties of primitive type cannot be optional.```
````

Comment: Which version of the `org.hidetake.swagger.generator` plugin are you using? There is a bug report for the plugin (https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin/issues/185) that mentions that without a fix the plugin will fail with Gradle 7.x - but that bug was fixed in the `org.hidetake.swagger.generator` plugin version 2.18.2 (at the time of commention version 2.19.2 is the latest version)

Comment: @ThomasKläger I changed version to 2.19.2 but I have all time problems with gradle... I pasted below error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this errors

If u need fix this problems you should check your:

- lombok version
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugi version
- try add springfox-boot-starter dependency (3.0.0)
- check version io.springfox:springfox-swagger
- org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin version
- check swagger files (.mustache files, gradle.build, version)
- try add org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens=java.util=ALL-UNNAMED to gradle properties